# Why do I get a Memory Error when trying to overwrite a variable in a while loop? (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, memory, while-loop

Hello I am new to python and decided to practice writing some algorithms.
The problem I am trying to solve can be found here if interested > http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/791/A

This is the code that I have written to solve that problem.

```
a = input("Enter Limak's weight:")
b = input("Enter Bob's Weight:")
i = 0

while (a < b):
    a = (a * 3)
    b = (b * 2)
    i= (i + 1)

print(i)
```

When I attempt to the run the code I receive the following error-

```
Enter Limak's weight:4
Enter Bob's Weight:7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 6, in <module>
    a = (a * 3)
MemoryError
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? It sounds like you're on Python 3, and you're multiplying strings instead of ints or floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce your crash using python 2.7.12.
Assuming you are using python 3, my guess is that your variables a and b are of type *str* and not *int*.
You need to cast them as *int* after reading them from the console.

Try changing:

```
a = input("Enter Limak's weight:")
```

with:

```
a = int(input("Enter Limak's weight:"))
```

And a little tip, in python you can write the expression:

```
i = i * 1
```

as

```
i += 1
```

As @Pfonks pointed out, this notation applies to most operators like *, - or /

Comment: also a = a *3 can be replaced with a *= 3. I just tested it. Without the int()-function I get an infinite loop. It works using the int()-function.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention i was using python3.4 thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I reproduced the infinite loop using python 3.5 ;)